# Удалить лишнюю переменную в цикле switch-case

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется [презентация](https://yadi.sk/d/2NJbDWOL7BgN3A). На 2 слайде в консоли отладки для более удобной отладки отображается переменная i2 и какой "case" сработал в цикле switch-case. При переходе на 3 слайд в консоли отладки отображается переменная i2 и i3. Необходимо удалить i2.

P.S.: `Reveal.addEventListener('slide2', function() { someCode });` - данный участок кода анимирует картинки при отображении на экране slide2.

Comment: Если честно, лично я, совсем не понял, что конкретно требуется. Запустил вашу страницу, походил туда-сюда, в логах выводится кучу строк при каждом нажатии , например, `slide 2 default right
test4.html:27069 4
test4.html:27167 slide 3 default right
test4.html:27171 4
test4.html:27065 slide 2 default right
test4.html:27069 4
test4.html:27167 slide 3 default right
test4.html:27171 4
test4.html:27065 slide 2 default right
test4.html:27069 4
test4.html:27157 slide 3 case 2 right 
test4.html:27158 3`. Какой i2 вам именно убрать надо

Comment: После того как вы перешли на 3 слайд с пустым экраном в консоли отладки вышло 4 надписи: slide 2 default right, далее 4 - это и есть i2 ( $('#rightbut').click(function() -> switch(i2) -> default). А дальше slide 3 default right, далее 1 - это задание переменной i3 значения равной 1 ( $('#rightbut').click(function() - > switch(i3) -> default )

Comment: у вас проблема не только в i2, вы дойдите до i4 и потом обратно. у вас будут выводиться i2/i3/i4 сразу. У вас ошибка в итерации , видимо где-то тут `while ( ( matched = handlerQueue[ i++ ] ) && !event.isPropagationStopped() ) {
   event.currentTarget = matched.elem;` но я могу ошибаться

Comment: Dred, в чем вы отладили код и как вы нашли? Спасибо.

Comment: @csharperbeginТак я ж ничего не нашел еще. Я только предположил. Дебажил в Chrome->F12. Ставите точку остановы на switch() и потом идете StepInto (F11) и смотрите как ваш код пошел дальше. А точнее, нужно идти не со switch а с самого метода, который начинает вам перелистывать страницу и создавать первую анимацию, так как у вас уже в самом начале есть i2

Comment: @Dred А у Вас может есть еще какие-нибудь идеи?

Comment: к сожалению,нет. Надо детально изучить ваш код. На первый взгляд,он не особо тривиален и много разных проверок происходит. Возможно его можно упростить,к тому же,если у вас есть switch-case.